# IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination cannot be found from the current destination Destination [Navigation Error]

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments, navigation

I am new to navigation graphs and navigation components in general and I am trying to pass data from the recycler view that's located in 'PrivSectionFragment' to 'PrivSectionDetailFragment'. Unfortunately, whenever I run the app I receive this error in my log

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination com.gazelle.wadifatk:id/action_privSectionFragment_to_privsDetailFragment cannot be found from the current destination Destination(com.gazelle.wadifatk:id/jobsFragment) label=الوظائف class=com.gazelle.wadifatk.jobLists.jobsFragment
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:940)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:877)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:863)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:1159)
    at com.gazelle.wadifatk.jobLists.PrivListAdapter.onBindViewHolder$lambda-0(PrivListAdapter.kt:55)
```

**This is where it refers** // it refers to my recycler adapter

```
PushDownAnim.setPushDownAnimTo(holder.card_view)
        //.setScale(PushDownAnim.MODE_SCALE, 0.89f)
        .setOnClickListener {
            val sendData = PrivSectionFragmentDirections
                .actionPrivSectionFragmentToPrivsDetailFragment(priv_list[position])
            Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(sendData)
        }
```

**This is my_nav.xml** // the blue circle
[image: my_nav photo]

keep in mind that I was able to pass the data from 'LatestNewsFragment' to 'NewsDetailsFragment'
just by using the same moves and I don't know why it accepted the data passing between those fragments and didn't accept it from 'PrivSectionFragment' to 'PrivSectionDetailFragment'.

**here is the code of the fragments**

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/my_nav"
app:startDestination="@id/latestNewsFragment">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/latestNewsFragment"
    android:name="com.gazelle.wadifatk.newsList.LatestNewsFragment"
    android:label="اخر الاخبار"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_latest_news" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_latestNewsFragment_to_jobsFragment"
        app:destination="@id/jobsFragment"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_enter_anim"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_default_exit_anim" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_latestNewsFragment_to_newsDetailFragment"
        app:destination="@id/newsDetailFragment"
        app:enterAnim="@android:anim/slide_in_left"
        app:exitAnim="@android:anim/slide_out_right"
        app:popEnterAnim="@android:anim/slide_in_left"
        app:popExitAnim="@android:anim/slide_out_right" />
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/jobsFragment"
    android:name="com.gazelle.wadifatk.jobLists.jobsFragment"
    android:label="الوظائف"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_jobs" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_jobsFragment_to_govSectionFragment"
        app:destination="@id/govSectionFragment" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_jobsFragment_to_privSectionFragment2"
        app:destination="@id/privSectionFragment" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_jobsFragment_to_latestNewsFragment"
        app:destination="@id/latestNewsFragment" />
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/privSectionFragment"
    android:name="com.gazelle.wadifatk.jobLists.PrivSectionFragment"
    android:label="PrivSectionFragment" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_privSectionFragment_to_privsDetailFragment"
        app:destination="@id/privsDetailFragment"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_enter_anim"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_default_exit_anim" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_privSectionFragment_to_jobsFragment"
        app:destination="@id/jobsFragment" />
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/newsDetailFragment"
    android:name="com.gazelle.wadifatk.newsList.NewsDetailFragment"
    android:label="التفاصيل"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_news_detail">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_newsDetailFragment_to_latestNewsFragment"
        app:destination="@id/latestNewsFragment"
        app:enterAnim="@android:anim/slide_in_left"
        app:exitAnim="@android:anim/slide_out_right"
        app:popEnterAnim="@android:anim/slide_in_left"
        app:popExitAnim="@android:anim/slide_out_right" />
    <argument
        android:name="news_data_list"
        app:argType="com.gazelle.wadifatk.newsList.NewsListViewModel" />

</fragment>

 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/privsDetailFragment"
    android:name="com.gazelle.wadifatk.jobLists.PrivsDetailFragment"
    android:label="التفاصيل"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_privs_detail" >

    <argument
        android:name="priv_data_list"
        app:argType="com.gazelle.wadifatk.jobLists.PrivListViewModel" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_privsDetailFragment_to_privSectionFragment"
        app:destination="@id/privSectionFragment" />

</fragment>
```

Here is a screen shot of the jobsFragment()

[image]

Comment: As per the error, you are in the `jobsFragment` while the navigation is being triggered.

Comment: How are `jobsFragment` and `PrivSectionFragment`related? Are you using ViewPager?

Comment: @Arpit Shukla  I am using tablayout so jobsFragments contains a viewpager with tablyaout and privsectionfragment is one of the tabs

Comment: Then you shouldn't put `PrivSectionFragment` inside nav graph. Use `jobsFragments` to navigate to `NewsDetailFragment`

Comment: Also, what's the use of `action_privSectionFragment_to_jobsFragment` ?

Comment: If i don't put the PrivSectionfragment to nav graph how do i use the safe-args then since it contains a rcycler view? and to answer your second question it's the arrow that goes back to jobs Fragment

Comment: 1. You can create an action from jobsFragment to privsDetailFragment. And you can pass your arguments using that action only. 2. Why do you have a back button from a tab view to container fragment? Can you add a screenshot of your screen in the question?

Comment: @ArpitShukla I'v added a screen shot you can see the arrow from privsectionfragment to jobsfragment

Comment: I meant a screenshot of your app (not the nav graph). privSectionFragment is a tab inside jobsFragment. Why do we need a back button here?

Comment: The nav graph and all of this are new to me.. shouldn't i have have a back button to go back to the main jobsFrag? Or it will be added auto?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of jobsFragment in your running app? Only then I will be able to suggest anything.

Comment: @ArpitShukla I've added an image of the jobsfragment as you can see there is a tablayout and 2 fragments i want to be able to send the recycler data to privdetailsfragment

Comment: Grt and where is your back button? I don't see any back button in PrivSectionfragment.

Comment: @Arpit shukla I deleted it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add only `JobsFragment` in your nav graph and add action in this fragment for `PrivsDetailFragment`.

```xml
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/jobsFragment"
    android:name="com.gazelle.wadifatk.jobLists.jobsFragment"
    android:label="الوظائف"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_jobs" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_jobsFragment_to_govSectionFragment"
        app:destination="@id/govSectionFragment" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_jobsFragment_to_latestNewsFragment"
        app:destination="@id/latestNewsFragment" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_jobsFragment_to_privsDetailFragment"
        app:destination="@id/privsDetailFragment"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_enter_anim"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_default_exit_anim" />
</fragment>
```

And then in you adapter, using this action:

```kotlin
PushDownAnim.setPushDownAnimTo(holder.card_view)
        //.setScale(PushDownAnim.MODE_SCALE, 0.89f)
        .setOnClickListener {
            val sendData = JobFragmentDirections.actionJobFragmentToPrivsDetailFragment(priv_list[position])
            Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(sendData)
        }
```

You can remove `privSectionFragment` from the nav graph.

Answer (score 1):

Verify if your destination needs arguments, if it's true, You could add in your action

```
    PushDownAnim.setPushDownAnimTo(holder.card_view)
        //.setScale(PushDownAnim.MODE_SCALE, 0.89f)
        .setOnClickListener {
            val sendData = PrivSectionFragmentDirections

    sendData.setNameExtra(valueExtra)
                .actionPrivSectionFragmentToPrivsDetailFragment(priv_list[position])
            Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(sendData)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just used the wrong directions in

```
findNavController().navigate(XFragmentDirections.toSomething)
```